Куда в screen-space отображаются края диапазона координат из clip-space?
Я знаю, что в OpenGL после проективного преобразования, т.е. в clip-space, координаты вершин (тех, что попадут на экран) находятся в кубе [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1], где координаты идут слева-направо, снизу-вверх и от далёких к близким. Но в screen-space координаты находятся в параллелепипеде [0, width]x[0, height]x[0, 1], где width и height - размеры окна и координаты также идут слева-направо, снизу-вверх и от далёких к близким. При этом пикселям соответствуют координаты их центров в screen-space и левый-нижний пиксель будет иметь координаты (0.5, 0.5), а правый-верхний - (width - 0.5, height - 0.5).
Вопрос, куда в screen-space отображаются края диапазона координат из clip-space? То есть если точка имела координаты (-1, -1) (z мне здесь не важен) в clip-space, отобразится ли она в (0.5, 0.5) в screen-space, т. е. в центр левого-нижнего пикселя, или в (0, 0), т. е. в левый-нижний угол левого-нижнего пикселя? Аналогично, отобразится ли (1, 1) в (width - 0.5, height - 0.5), т. е. в центр правого-верхнего пикселя, или в (width, height), т. е. в правый-верхний угол правого-верхнего пикселя?

@Kromster я его задаю как обычно вызовом glViewport(0, 0, width, height);. Вот я и хочу понять, что именно этот вызов делает. Как это можно попробовать?

@Kromster и что? Изображение будет полоской шириной в 0 пикселей?

Перепутал с glOrtho, точно )

https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_fragment_coord_conventions.txt
